# Сжатие String в Servlet

Tags: java

Преподаватель задал задачу, метод get создает большой String result (с помощью цикла, получается около 1 мб при выводе на экран ) и вызывает метод post. Метод post выводит result в браузере. Но еще стоит задача, если я понял правильно, перед выводом в post сжать result, чтобы уменьшить объем передаваемой информации в браузер. Как это сделать?
Вот код

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class StringServlet extends HttpServlet {

    String sentence = "With Java EE metadata annotations, the standard web.xml deployment descriptor is now optional.";
    String result;


    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4000; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(sentence + " ");
        }
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
//что-то сделать с result
        PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        printWriter.write("<h1 style='font-size:25px'>" + result + "</h1>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены что надо что-то сделать с `result`? Я бы сказал, что надо что-то сделать с `Content-Encoding`. Например установить его в `gzip`. Но это делается не в коде, а в настройках конкретного аппликейшен-севреа, куда деплоится приложение.

Comment: Класс сервлета не должен иметь непотокобезопасные поля как у вас     String result; Это может вызвать ошибки